# How to access a field in relation in eloquent orm

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent, relationship, data-retrieval

I wrote this code to get the product information with it's images and category:

```
            ->where('category_id', 5)
            ->with('category', 'Files')->get();
```

my result is:

```
{
        "id": 2,
        "name": "test",
        "price": 13000,
        "description": "some text ...",
        "shop_id": 1,
        "rate": 0,
        "category_id": 5,
        "discount_percent": 20,
        "category": {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "cat1",
            "shop_id": 1
        },
        "files": [
            {
                "id": 99,
                "disk_name": "5ef1af07d6d98778754621.jpg",
                "file_name": "13330983_xl.jpg",
                "file_size": 69813,
                "content_type": "image/jpeg",
                "title": null,
                "description": null,
                "field": "product_gallery",
                "sort_order": 99,
                "created_at": "2020-06-23 07:28:07",
                "updated_at": "2020-06-23 07:28:10",
                "path":...... storage/app/uploads/public/5ef/1af/07d/5ef1af07d6d98778754621.jpg",
                "extension": "jpg"
            }
        ]
    }
```

now i want to access the path field, how can i do it?
i use this way for access but i don't get result:

```
products[0].files[0].path
```

Comment: Eloquent return object and you have to access the object please use -> instead of .

Comment: i use twig tag {{ products[0].files[0].path }} @PankajBisht

Comment: try to it ```data_get($products[, '0.files.0.path'')```

Comment: Sure but you are using ->get() add ->toArray() to it

Answer (score 1):

You should use toArray() function to convert data likes this

```
->where('category_id', 5)
->with('category', 'Files')->get()->toArray();
```

And then access

```
products[0]['files'][0]['path']
```